# ofstream, ifstream c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть один файл `ofstream fout("fout.txt");` передаю его в 2 функции, в первой функции в него нужно сделать запись, а во второй функции нужно считать его, т.е.сначала получается он выступает как ofstream, потом как ifstream. Как можно сделать правильно? Чтобы передать его как ifstream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам надо и писать и читать, используйте просто fstream (без o- и без i-), открытый в режиме чтения и записи одновременно. Например:

```
fstream file("Notebook.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
```

Comment: при изменении на fstream, методы ifstream пропадают?например get

Comment: оказывается некоторые методы сохраняются ,все работает спасибо!